# Any field is euclidean domain

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory

In many sources I have seen that in order to prove that any field is euclidean domain we need to take function $d:F-\{0\}\mapsto \mathbb{Z}_{\geq 0}$ and mostly $d$ is taken to be the $d(x)=1$ for any nonzero $x\in F$.

But if I define the function $d$ in different way, namely $d(x)=0$ for any nonzero $x\in F$ then everything still be fine.

1) $d(xy)\geq d(y)$ holds for any nonzero $x,y\in F$.

2) If $a,b\in F$ where $b\neq 0$  then $\exists q,r\in R$ such that $a=bq+r$. In our case we can take $r=0, q=b^{-1}a$.

P.S. In general we can take $d(x)=k$ where $k$ is any nonnegative integer.

Am I right? Would be very grateful for help.

Comment: We generally don't think of **fields** as Euclidean domains; a field only has two ideals, $F$ and $\{0\}$.

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown, Thanks for reply! But I am aksing if I define the function $d$ in the following is it correct or not?

Comment: @RFZ Yes, correct, see the duplicate. The answer is the same as you wrote under 2).